# Access on a Field

Tags: 7, users

I have a content type with some fields I've created and I also have 2 roles: A Client and A Technician.

I want the client to be able to fill in this new content type which is a support ticket, but I don't want them to have access to a field for assigning the job.  How can I stop access to this field for the client, but make it visible and usable for the technician role?  What I think I'm looking for is the Access Control Module but with the ability to grant access per field rather than node.

Thanks

Kieran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions).